# Slicing in python similar to MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, list, slice

In Matlab, slice can be a vector:

```
a = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'}; % cell array
b = a([1:3,5,7]);
```

How can I do the same thing in python?

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
b = [a[i] for i in [0,1,2,4,6]]
```

but when 1:3 becomes 1:100, this will not work. Using range(2),4,6 returns ([0,1,2],4,6), not (0,1,2,4,6). Is there a fast and "pythonic" way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to do things that are similar to Matlab in Python, NumPy should always be your first guess.  In this case, you need `numpy.r_`:

```
from numpy import array, r_
a = array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
print a[r_[1:3, 5, 7]]

['b' 'c' 'f' 'h']
```

Comment: ++, nice one, had no idea about `r_`

Comment: Note that `r_[:3, 5:]` returns `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` since it has no knowledge of a. Workaround is to use `r_[:3, 5:len(a)]` which returns `[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]`. still the closest thing you will find to Matlab type slicing.

Answer (score 5):

One way is using `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> b = [a[i] for i in itertools.chain(range(2), [5, 6])]
>>> b
['b', 'c', 'f', 'g']
```

Notes:

1. Ranges adapted from Matlab (1-based indexing) to Python (0-based indexing)
2. You may gain by changing `range` to `xrange` if you have Python 2.x, to avoid creating the whole range list on the fly. I don't think it will make a big performance difference, but it's nice to know about.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
[a[i] for i in range(2) + [4, 6]]
```

If you use NumPy, then you have some more options:

```
import numpy as N
a = N.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
b = a[range(2) + [4, 6]]
c = a.take(range(2) + [4, 6])
```

Comment: This will copy the list though. Wasteful with larger ranges. Use `itertools.chain` to avoid that.